# Yii upload a file using a model

Tags: php, yii

I am simply trying to upload a file using a model. I get the exception message in the current situation (see model/controller/view below):

```
CException
MyFile and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "save".
```

If my model extends CActiveRecord instead of CFormModel there is an another Exception:

```
CDbException
The table "MyFile" for active record class "MyFile" cannot be found in the database.
```

What is my mistake? These are the files:

**MODEL: MyFile.php**

```
class MyFile extends CFormModel {
    public $image;
    public function rules () {
        return array (
            array ('image', 'file', 'types' => 'gif, jpg, png'),
        );
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER: MyFileController.php**

```
class MyFileController extends CController {
    public function actionCreate() {
        $model = new MyFile;

        if(isset($_POST['MyFile'])) {

            $model->attributes=$_POST['MyFile'];
            $model->image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            if($model->save()) {
                $path = Yii::app()->runtimePath.'/temp/uploadDirectory/'.$model->image;
                $model->image->saveAs($path);
            }
        }
        $this->render('create', array('model'=>$model));
    }
}
```

**VIEW: create.php**

```
 <h1>File-Upload</h1>

 <?php

    echo CHtml::form('','post',array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'));
    echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'image');
    echo CHtml::submitButton('abschicken', array('name' => 'submit'));
    echo CHtml::endForm();

 ?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CFormModel` doesn't have a method named `save()`, if you want to call it you have to implement it, but what you want in your case is to use the `validate` method

And if `MyFile` doesn't have a related db table then it shouldn't extend `CActiveRecord`.

You can validate that the uploaded image is a gif, a png or a jpg by calling `validate()` :

```
class MyFileController extends CController {
    public function actionCreate() {
        $model = new MyFile;

        if(isset($_POST['MyFile'])) {

            $model->attributes=$_POST['MyFile'];
            $model->image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            if($model->validate()) {
                //The image is valid, you can save it
                $path = Yii::app()->runtimePath.'/temp/uploadDirectory/'.$model->image;
                $model->image->saveAs($path);
            }
            $this->render('create', array('model'=>$model));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I have a table and I am using CActiveRecord. Now I have an another Exception: Missing the temporary folder to store the uploaded file "xyz.jpg".

Comment: Hum the folder `Yii::app()->runtimePath.'/temp/uploadDirectory/'` exists? if not then you should create it before saving the image with something like `mkdir($yourPath, 0775, true)` (`true` is to recursively create the folders)

Comment: yes, the directory exists, the same error message.. I think, I must set the temporary directory somewhere in the setting, but I currently do not know, where?

Comment: I've found it: On the test-server there was no entry in the php.ini file at "upload_tmp_dir". I've changed it to /var/tmp

Answer (score 0):

```
  public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Item;
    if (isset($_POST['Item'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Item'];
        $model->images = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'images');
        if ($model->save()) {
            $path = Yii::app()->basePath . '/../uploads/' . $model->images;
            $model->images->saveAs($path);
            // redirect to success page
        }
    }
    $this->render('upload', array('model' => $model));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $img = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');
        $randomNAme = hash('sha512',$model->file);

        $path = Yii::app()->basePath.'/'.'uploads/'.$img;
        $img->saveAs($path);
```

Comment: use this to store the file uploaded using Yii 1